# Webpack pass env variables after build

Tags: javascript, webpack, yarnpkg

My use case is the following. I make a production build like this:

```
cross-env API_URL=my_url yarn build
```

and then run it like this:

```
yarn start:prod
```

and it all works ok. But what I want to be able to do is:

```
yarn build
```

and then start it like:

```
cross-env API_URL=my_url yarn start:prod
```

so that I can test the same build against different backend environments. Is this doable?
Right now, if I try it, the API_URL doesn't get picked up after build and it defaults to the one I have in an .env file (because I support a default case). I'm aware that Webpack needs the env variables during build, but maybe there's a workaround I'm missing.

My build script, inside package.json is:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production env-cmd .env.prod --no-override --config config/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout
```

and my start:prod script is:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production env-cmd .env-prod --no-override node server
```